# Laravel: global variable based on session accessible via ENTIRE application (including tests and policies)

Tags: laravel

My application allows users to be apart of different accounts. On each account, they may have varying roles. I essentially want to do what Mailchimp does.

A user can be the "owner" of one account, while only an author on another.

But if I'm logged as a user who's an owner on one account, and then I want to "switch accounts", how can I handle this change in the application?

Currently I'm grabbing the user's first account model

`auth()->user()->accounts()->first`

If I want to allow them to switch to another account, how can I globally handle this and remember their choice across the application and every route.

I understand how to grab a specific model like `Account::find($id)`, but this needs to be global and then in every controller I need to reference `currentAccount` somehow.

Edit:

So I have a good idea on how to actually manage the account ID via sessions. I put together some very simple logic on setting the current account based on session data. I just put this on a controller route and returned the data for testing:

```
public function getCurrentAccount(Request $request) {

        $request->session()->put('account_id', 3);

        $account_id = $request->session()->get('account_id');
        $user = auth()->user();

        if ($account_id) {
            $account = Account::findOrFail($account_id);

            if ($user->accounts->contains($account->id)) {
                $this->account = $account;
            } else {
                dd('error');
            }
        } else {
            $this->account = auth()->user()->accounts()->first();
        }
        return $this->account;
    }
```

So the above is the basic logic I need to apply. simple enough. However, I don't really know WHERE to put the initial session value.

And then I need to make a variable based on the session data accessible to all controllers, views, policies / authorization, tests, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, information you want to persist during a user's visit is kept in a session variable. You probably will need a step *after* they log in that allows them to select what account they will be working with unless you want to default them to a favorite or something. The session variable holding the account's ID, for example, will be available everywhere with Laravel's global `session` function.

You will likely provide a form that submits to a route to change the active account. In that route's method, you can do:

```php
// assign session key to a value
session(['account_id' => $request->input('account_id')]);
```

then, to access it when in other routes you can do:

```php
// get session key's value
session('account_id')
```

Refer to this documentation if you need more details: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#using-the-session

Comment: Thank you! I think this will put my in the right direction. Remembering the ID only in sessions is a good idea. And then I'll figure out how to make a global account variable that's available throughout the app.

Comment: I had to uncheck best answer only because I'm still unsure of where to initially set my session variable and how to make a global variable across the application (based on session value). I need the global variable to be accessible on all controller requests, views, policies / authorization, tests, etc.

Comment: @good_afternoon the global variable isn't based on a session value, the session value **is the global variable**. Where you initially assign the session variable is up to you. It can be when they log in or by forcing them to select an account right after log in. you take that value and give it to the session like this: `session(['account_id' => <your_account_id>])`. Then you access it with: `session('account_id')` and that is usable globally. If you need to get the details of that account you can do `Account::find(session('account_id'))`